# Writing to file with sys.stdout in python

Tags: python, sys

```
ascii85.encode(file('/work/file1'), sys.write('/work/file2')
```

I am trying to write to a file with this code using sys.stdout, but it is not writing.

How do I fix the code to write to a file?

Comment: Please read the line of code and try to understand what it is doing before asking a question.

Comment: i'm just trying to do it in the python shell. It works if i use: ascii85.encode(file('/work/file1'), sys.stdout  but it obviously prints to the screen which i don't want

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
ascii85.encode(file('/work/file1'), open('/work/file2', 'w'))
```

I don't know what exactly you're trying to do but that's how you open a file for writing in Python.

If this isn't what you want please clarify your question.